# extract nameidentifier claim from windows live

Tags: c#, azure, live, claims-based-identity, acs

I need to extract nameidentifier claim from windows live. I searched for the code, most of the places, I found using Azure access control service. I don't want to use Azure ACS. Is it possible to achieve this only using C#, asp.net?

Comment: Bear in mind that the UI given by LiveID is not a global identifier for a specific user, but in relation to the app/system requesting it. For example: 2 ACS namespaces might get 2 different UI for the same LiveID user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to get a SAML token back from Live ID? If so, the NameIdentifier should be found within the saml:Subject.

If your website is using WIF, then after a successful authentication you should already find this nameidentifier claim  inside the IClaimsPrincipal object. (e.g. HttpContext.Current.User)

Comment: I am just keen in extracting nameidentifier from Windows Live. I need to configure those nameidentifer in our database. This process may not be necessarily authentication. Can we do this in windows application using webbrowser object.